# Ionic partial swipe

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, swipe

How to implement partial swipe in Ionic framework?
I mean this flow:
1) If user done the full swipe from right to left works one handler.
2) If user done not full swipe and stops before item center - another handler.

`ion-option-button` directive realize only full swipe. Maybe someone have some fresh ideas about partial swipe. I'm using Ionic 1.3.

I have this HTML markup:

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="task in incident.currentIncidentsTasks" can-swipe="true" option-buttons="itemButtons" show-delete="false">
                            <ion-option-button side="left" id="failed-swipe"><img src="img/ic_failed_swipe.png"></ion-option-button>
                            <ion-option-button id="change-swipe"><img src="img/ic_change_swipe.png"></ion-option-button>
                            <ion-option-button id="in-progress-swipe"><img src="img/ic_inprogress_swipe.png"></ion-option-button>
                            <ion-option-button id="message-swipe"> <img src="img/ic_message_swipe.png"> </ion-option-button>
                            <ion-option-button id="confirmation-swipe"><img src="img/ic_confirm_swipe.png"></ion-option-button>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="col col-10 ">
                                    <img src="img/checked.png ">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-10 ">
                                    <div><img src="img/priority_task/{{task.Priority}}.png "></div>
                                    <div id="chat-img-tasks"><img src="img/chat.png "></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-50 ">
                                    <div class="task-detail-center ">{{task.Name}}</div>
                                    <div class="task-detail-center ">{{task.Description}}</div>


                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-30 ">
                                    <div class="task-detail "><img src="img/face.png "></div>
                                    <div class="task-detail ">AG: {{vm.currentTaskUser}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ion-item>
```

Thanks for attention and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that will help somebody.
Main idea is in tracking `drag` event(`ontouchmove` event works well on debugger, but on device doesn't work).
Set events while render page:

```
$ionicGestune.on('dragstart', vm.touchStartTrack, element);
$ionicGestune.on('dragend', vm.touchEndTrack, element);
```

Then track dragend event:

```
 function touchEndTrack(event) {
            if (event.gesture.distance > 370 && event.gesture.direction === "left") {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    vm.isFullSwipe = false;
                    vm.isHideOptions = true;
                });
            } else {
                vm.isFullSwipe = true;
                revertToDefaultTask();
            }
        }
```

Template:

```
<ion-item ng-show="swipe.isFullSwipe && swipe.isFail && swipe.isInProgress" show-delete="false" option-buttons="itemButtons">
```

If someone have better idea - please post your ideas.
Thanks for attention!